# Primefaces + Bootstrap Admin LTE Conflito jQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsf, primefaces

Já trabalho com Primefaces desde a versão 2.1 e atualmente estou criando um projeto na versão 5 utilizando o AdminLTE (http://almsaeedstudio.com/AdminLTE/) que é um painel administrativo utilizando a base do bootstrap.

O meu problema é o seguinte: criei o template com ui:decorate e comecei a criar minhas páginas. O problema é que, as páginas que contém componentes do Primefaces os componentes do AdminLTE, mais especificamente o jQuery, parão de funcionar. O menu lateral não esconde e não expande mais os itens.

Tentei de várias formas resolver este conflito, mas o que percebi que só o jQuery do AdminLTE é que para de funcionar, os componentes do primefaces funcionam tranquilamente. Se alguém tiver alguma ideia de como resolver fico grato.

Answer (score 1):

O primefaces também utiliza o Jquery na sua implementação, e adiciona automaticamente um import ao jquery na versão que ele precisa.

no arquivo [index.html](https://github.com/almasaeed2010/AdminLTE/blob/master/index.html) do AdminLTE também existe um import para o JQuery

```
 <!-- jQuery 2.0.2 -->
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Importar o jquery 2 vezes pode causar problemas no seu funcionamento, remova qualquer import ao jquery.min.js ou jquery.js, ou qualquer outro arquivo .js que esteja sendo importado 2x e deixe apenas o que vira por padrão com o Primefaces.

Comment: Na verdade o que estou procurando agora é uma forma de fazer o Primefaces importar o jQuery para todas as páginas. No meu caso a página index não possui componentes que dependam do jQuery nativo do Primefaces e nestes casos ele não importa. Quando faço a importação do jQuery ele simplesmente para de funcionar para o Bootstrap ou para o Primefaces. Assim que descobrir a solução posto para todos.

Answer (score 1):

Estou trabalhando com o mesmo template consegui resolver o caso da seguinte forma:
1 coloquei no head o seguinte codigo
 
        jQuery(document).ready(function(jQuery){
        });
     
2 removi o jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js do template assim consegui evitar o conflito